# Где хранить единичные данные в Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, python-3.5

Где хранить единичные данные в Django v1.10.1 и Python v3.5, например:

- Названия сайта,
- Номер телефона,
- Логотип,
- Описание.

И необходимо изменять через админку.

Comment: Я себе завёл обычную модель и храню это всё отдельно для каждого языка сайта, но есть и решения вроде [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, пока остановился на `django-solo`, хотя пока не смотрел как хранится это в базе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил данную задачу средствами [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo), пример:

models.py:

```
 # models.py

from django.db import models
from solo.models import SingletonModel

class SiteConfiguration(SingletonModel):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Имя сайта ')
    maintenance_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Конфигурация Сайта"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Конфигурация Сайта"
```

admin.py:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from solo.admin import SingletonModelAdmin
from config.models import SiteConfiguration

admin.site.register(SiteConfiguration, SingletonModelAdmin)
```

views.py:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from config.models import SiteConfiguration

def main(request):
    ConfSiteConfiguration = SiteConfiguration.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'config': ConfSiteConfiguration})
```

template:

```
{% load solo_tags %}
{% get_solo 'config.SiteConfiguration' as site_config %}
{{ site_config.site_name }}
{{ site_config.maintenance_mode }}
```

Код в примере взял из документации [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo)

Answer (score 2):

Что касается именно джанго, то у админки таких инструментов нет. Админка джанги - это высокоуровневый интерфейс для работы именно с базой данных.

Как вариант это сделать отдельную таблицу для этих данных.

Если неохота, то можно сделать самому странички для админки. Единичные данные можно хранить в любом файле. Или воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками, которые решают подобные задачи.

Comment: @215517 и просто не давать пользователю записать больше 1 записи?